# How to setup eclipse with blackberry jde's already installed on Windows 7 machine?

Tags: blackberry, jde

I found many posts on the forum regarding this problem which navigates me to No Page found error.
Does any body know how can I add the Blackberry JDE's that already installed on my machine.

Any help is appreciable.
Thanks in advance.

---

Thanks zechariahs for the reply,
Actually, My main problem is that,
I am using Windows 7 machine which is 64 bit supported both OS as well as machine H/W.

I tried a lot to install the Blackberry in Eclipse - Hellios, Galilo of 32-bit and JDK 1.5 
Also tried with same for 64 bit and JDK 1.6 
but it is not at all getting installed.

By reading post, I tried with 
h:\New\eclipse\eclipse -vm C:\jdk\jre\bin\javaw.exe command also,
but no success.

Any how I wanna run Blackberry program on My 64-bit Windows 7 Machine,

Can you please suggest any thing ?

Answer (score 1):

The Blackberry eclipse plugin is for 32bit version of Eclipse and Java sdk.
You must install all 32bit version.